# Bootstrap4 adjacent navbar columns

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, styling

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation" id="navbar">
      <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mynav" href="{% url 'home' %}">Star Social</a>
              <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}

                      <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Groups</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Create Group</a></li>
                      <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>

                  {% else %}
                    <li><a href="">Group</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
                  {% endif %}
              </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

I have a code like this but when I run the server, I'm getting style like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Your bootstrap code tag you forgot to add class in `<li>` and `<a>` and you must replace the class in ul tag `navbar-right` to `ml-auto` here i will change

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation" id="navbar">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Star Social</a>

              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                 <!-- {% if user.is_authenticated %} -->
                      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="">Posts</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Group</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Create Group</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Logout</a></li>

               <!--   {% else %} -->

                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Group</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}">Login</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}">Signup</a></li>
       <!--           {% endif %} -->
              </ul>
    </nav>
```

Above try but it not collapse if you want do same please refer a docs of bootstrap here i give link [Bootstrap Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/) it work make right so let me know

Comment: it worked but i want to show the categories top right align. The navbar-right code isnt working with this code

Comment: hii @sonelektrikci  i update my answer can you try this may it work perfect